# Binding an ItemsControl containing WindowsFormHost items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, data-binding

I am building a UI element for our WPF application that allows a user to visualize a collection of graphs aligned in a grid format. As I understand, you can use an ItemsControl with a WrapPanel that will nicely align ui elements in a grid format.

The difficulty comes when we try to use a winforms graphing library (zedgraph) to generate the graphs. This means we have to use `WindowsFormsHost` to display the graph views. I have tried to bind the graph collection using the normal data binding, it doesn't really work:

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Graphs}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WindowsFormsHost Margin="5">
                <ui:Graph></ui:Graph>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The above code displays nothing, but the Graphs getter is accessed.

Also, even if I cancel the binding and I just insert some random graph views inside the ItemsControl... it still doesn't display anything:

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <WindowsFormsHost Margin="5">
        <ui:Graph></ui:Graph>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
    <WindowsFormsHost Margin="5">
    </WindowsFormsHost>
        <ui:Graph></ui:Graph>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
    <WindowsFormsHost Margin="5">
        <ui:Graph></ui:Graph>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</ItemsControl>
```

To test to make sure the graphing library functions normally, this does indeed display a graph:

```
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost Margin="5">
        <ui:Graph></ui:Graph>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Much appreciated.

Comment: I strongly suggest creating a `UserControl` to host your winforms stuff and create DependencyProperties in this UserControl so that you can get Binding capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any idea why the non-bind version doesn't display? Graphs display nicely outside of `ItemsControl`, but not inside `ItemsControl`.

Comment: I guess that might be related to layout. winforms is horrible, and requires that you hardcode the sizes of everything. Try giving a fixed hardcoded `Width` and `Height` to the winformshost.

Comment: That did it... Setting hardcoded sizes for the graphs works. In fact, the binding also works. You should put it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be related to layout. winforms is horrible, and requires that you hardcode the sizes of everything.

Try giving a fixed hardcoded Width and Height to the winformshost

Comment: Confirmed this also works for getting WindowsFormsHost to play nice in a WrapPanel. However hosting an external app in there has display issues :/